# Angular get src from async function result in timout

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a little question :). I am trying to get image src from async function, but so far i am not doing good I have this:

```
<img [src]="getProductImage(articleNumber)"/>
```

and in typescript:

```
public async getProductImage(articleNumber:string): Promise<string> {
let result = await this._Service.product(articleNumber);
debugger;

return result.imageFullUrl
}
```

In the debugger i can see that result.imageFullUrl is populated, but after that my page hangs and becomes unresponsive.
Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using `toPromise()` in the service to convert an observable to a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you're binding a function or expression to a property like `[src]="getProductImage(articleNumber)"` and using default change detection strategy, the function will be triggered for each CD cycle. So most probably the function is triggered too many times (check the console) and app becomes unresponsive.
2. It's better to initialize a variable to hold the image `src` data in the controller and use it in the template.

Controller

```js
public imageSrc: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this._Service.product(articleNumber)
    .then(result => { this.imageSrc = result.imageFullUrl; });
}
```

Template

```html
<img [src]="imageSrc"/>
```

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you for help, solution you posted works for me :).